# Objeto en formato string dentro de valor de un JSON

Tags: javascript, json, string, parsear

Bueno tengo el siguiente JSON:

```
{
  "creatorId": "#1",
  "data": {
            "id": "10",
            "creator": "#1"
        },
  "subs": ["1"]
}
```

Pero el contenido de data no debe de ser un objeto. Sino un objecto en formato string.

```
{
  "creatorId": "#1",
  "data": "{
              \"id\": \"10\",
              \"creator\": \"#1\"
            }",
  "subs": ["1"]
}
```

Todo esto es debido a que mi intencion es recoger el campo data del JSON y convertirlo en un objeto js.

```
const dataObj = JSON.parse(recoverJson.data);
```

Y claro lo más sencillo sería pasarle directamente el objecto y no tener que estar recogiendo el string y así. Pero es requisito de API que lo que llegue sea un string.

Como podria montar el JSON con un objeto "strigificado"

Comment: prueba,antes de añadir el contenido, a hacer un JSON.Stringify, me refiero al objeto data, antes de agrgarlo al JSON

Comment: prueba con `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(recoverJson.data))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te lo pongo en varios pasos para que quede claro, pero puedes ahorrarte algunas de las variables intermedias:

```js
const jsonOriginal= `{
  "creatorId": "#1",
  "data": {
            "id": "10",
            "creator": "#1"
        },
  "subs": ["1"]
}`;

const obj = JSON.parse(jsonOriginal); //obtenemos el objeto

const data= obj.data; //nos quedamos con el campo que queremos como string

const dataString = JSON.stringify(data); //lo transformamos a string

console.log(dataString);

obj.data = dataString; //reemplazamos el objeto por su JSON equivalente

const nuevoJson= JSON.stringify(obj,null,2); //transformamos a JSON

console.log('El resultado', nuevoJson);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu siempre completa respuesta !!!

Answer (score 2):

Bueno estaba montando mal los caracteres de escape. Asi que he dado con la solucion pero de manera programatica. Siguiendo las sugerencias de los comentarios. He montado el siguiente codigo:

```js
let data = {"id": "10","creator": "#1"};
let x = {"creatorId": "#1","data": "","subs": ["1"]};
x.data = JSON.stringify(data);

console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
```